# Telegram: Bad Request: failed to get HTTP URL content: two similar links: one works, one doesn't

Tags: http, url, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to send two gifs to Telegram:

First:

```
https://preview.redd.it/1dsyzqgv3os21.gif?s=c4c426909c653ae159c6bd36a79542245b8dd124
```

Request link:

```
 https://api.telegram.org/botXXX...XXX/sendAnimation?chat_id=@XXXX&animation=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.redd.it%2F1dsyzqgv3os21.gif%3Fs%3Dc4c426909c653ae159c6bd36a79542245b8dd124
```

Second:

```
https://external-preview.redd.it/LD9iy2VqTJPrkBtOCKE9jBdJA3003epxng2LwOIzBzk.gif?s=75a8452ac1000ef27b7cf95b6535163b8cd671ec
```

Request link:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botXXX...XXX/sendAnimation?chat_id=@XXXX&animation=https%3A%2F%2Fexternal-preview.redd.it%2FLD9iy2VqTJPrkBtOCKE9jBdJA3003epxng2LwOIzBzk.gif%3Fs%3D75a8452ac1000ef27b7cf95b6535163b8cd671ec
```

Despite them being rather similar in their structure, only the first one works.

When I try to send the second request I get:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error_code": 400,
    "description": "Bad Request: failed to get HTTP URL content"
}
```

Why is that? What can I do to fix it?